DevContainer attatch to new image container in vscode？
I use wsl environment and vscode editor.I reopen project in devcontainer and make some changes to current container,so I use docker commit to create a new image.But current container is still use origin image, how do I change the current container to use the new created image?
I use docker run to create a new container based on new created image. when I reopen the project in the new container, the editor cannot load project files.

You have to set the image in your devcontainer.json.
See here
